# Why is there a difference between calcsize("!BHB") and calcsize("BHB")?

Tags: python, struct

Using the struct module in python 2.4.3 why is there a difference between calcsize("!BHB") and calcsize("BHB")?
whereby;
when

```
from struct import *
calcsize("!BHB") == 4
calcsize("BHB") == 5
```

I understand the big endian and little endian concept, but don't really get it in terms of bytes placement for the above formats.

Comment: Did some tinkering and observed that 'BH' is 4 and '!BH' is 3. 'HB', however, is 3. So the question can probably be simplified to "Why is calcsize('BH') == 4?"

Comment: Although you are using a module from Python's stdlib, when you ask questions you have to be clar about which module you are talking about. The "struct" module which you are using is not part of the language specification -a nd people can have some difficulties to find out what are you talking about.

Comment: exactly what I intended. But the thought of putting an extra character to allow viewers test the shorter characters on their own wins me over..  --Choe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for that is explained in the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) and it is due to padding issue when you are using a mixed structure members (BHB)

1. Padding is only automatically added between successive structure members. 
   No padding is added at the beginning or the end of the encoded struct.
2. No padding is added when using non-native size and alignment, 
   e.g. with ‘<’, ‘>’, ‘=’, and ‘!’.

See this:

```
>>> struct.pack("BHB",1,1,1)
'\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01'
>>> struct.pack("=BHB",1,1,1)
'\x01\x01\x00\x01'
```

In the first case, the padding was added to Byte because it was using the default native size and alignment and you explicitly set it standard size using '=', no padding was done.